# Reveal.js How to use floating images in animations

Tags: reveal.js

I am looking at making an animation using `auto-animate` and 2 slides.

The animation is made of 5 images.

Using `<image>` stack me the images on an horizontal line .. using `div`s stack them vertically.

I would like the second slide to arrange the images on a diagonal.

The best for me would be to position the images freely but I don't know how to do that :( ?

Answer (score 0):

To position an item in CSS, try this:

```
<style>
    #image1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
</style>
<img src='my-image.jpg' id='image1'/>
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp for more details.

:)